# Can I use `map` with fixed input?

Tags: mapping, julia

Suppose I do `f(x,y) = 2x + y`then `map(f, [2,4,6],[1,1,1])`
I will get:

```
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  5
  9
 13
```

---

If I do `map(f, [2,4,6],1)`, i.e., I want to suppose that the second input is always the same, 
I will get:

```
1-element Array{Any,1}:
5
```

So this does not work. Is there a way to do this without coding a Vector `[1,1,1]` ?

Comment: See also this related question covering fixed keyword arguments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906788/julia-passing-arguments-to-function-through-the-map-function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Broadcast "acts like" it changes the arrays to be a size which works, and maps:

`broadcast(f, [2,4,6],1)`

outputs:

```
Int64[3]
5
9
13
```

Comment: Is there a parallel equivalent to broadcast, as pmap() is to map() ?

Comment: There can be [if you let the developers know that you want one here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/17887). There are some implementation details that would need to get  worked out (`map` doesn't need to share data between the independent runs, whereas `broadcast` needs to share the small vector in some sense), but if my proposal gets enough backing, there should be a `pbroadcast()`, and also things like `tbroadcast()` for threading. See the issue.

Comment: Awesome. This would be great. I'll put my plug in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map(x->f(x,1), [2,4,6])` to accomplish this.