# Julia: Passing keyword arguments to function through the map() function

Tags: function, arguments, mapping, julia

I am trying to use `map()` to apply the function `quandl` on an array of (n x 1) strings. (http://quandljl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_data.html)

However, I wish to pass on more than just the strings as arguments to the function, such as `from = Date1` and `to = Date2`. I cannot seem to find a way to have `map()` apply the function on the array of strings while also passing the keyword arguments to download data from `Date1` to `Date2`.

The more general question is: how can I use `map()` to apply a function on several elements while also passing additional arguments to this function?

Comment: See also this related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853197/can-i-use-map-with-fixed-input/38853852#38853852

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll want to create an anonymous function that calls `quandl` with the appropriate arguments and map that over your data. Since I'm a little unclear on how you want to call `quandl`, I'll just use a made up example. Suppose `f` takes two positional arguments and a keyword `k`; suppose you want to apply it to each value of `v` with `2` as the second argument and `k = "abc"`. You would do this like so:

```
map(x -> f(x, 2, k = "abc"), v)
```

If the anonymous function body is large or complicated, you may want to use Julia's [do-block syntax](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/functions/#do-block-syntax-for-function-arguments) and write the computation like this instead:

```
map(v) do x
    f(x, 2, k = "abc")
end
```

In this example, this doesn't make much sense, but if the anonymous function is multiple lines of code, then this can be preferable.